# Looping a Task in Main()

Tags: c#, loops, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have this

```
foreach (FileInfo flInfo in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                String name = flInfo.Name;
                Console.WriteLine("{0, -30:g} ", name);
                Task<DataTable> mergeTable = processFile(name);
                 table.Merge(mergeTable.Result);
            }
```

How can I loop this task< DataTable > with different variable mergeTable?

To be more specific on what I am asking for
Currently I am doing this.

```
Task<DataTable> mergeTable01 = processFile("filename1.txt");
Task<DataTable> mergeTable02 = processFile("filename2.txt");
Task<DataTable> mergeTable03 = processFile("filename3.txt");
Task<DataTable> mergeTable04 = processFile("filename4.txt");

Task.WaitAll(mergeTable01,mergeTable02,mergeTable03,mergeTable04);

table.Merge(mergeTable01.Result);
table.Merge(mergeTable02.Result);
table.Merge(mergeTable03.Result);
table.Merge(mergeTable04.Result);
```

How can I loop this repeating task and finally merge the datatable?

Comment: did you try to place the task inside a loop?

Comment: Hi Alexei,
What do you mean?

Comment: You've asked how to loop, Alexei has asked if you've considered a loop, and you're confused? What exactly do you mean by processing with "different variable mergeTable" ? There's also nothing asynchronous about this code, nor does it use `async-await`

Comment: Hi ColinM, I tried foreach loop and posted here. But Alexei asked if I am considering a loop. I am confused. 
I had give example, on what I need. How can I create a loop the repeating task?

Comment: You haven't explained what exactly you're wanting to achieve as it seems you already have code which does this in a loop. Can you be more specific?

Comment: With loop, I am not able to wait for all the task to complete before merge. 
Without loop, I have to hardcode the number of task but I can have waitAll task to complete before I merge all the table.
so how can I have loop and waitAll before I merge the table

Comment: In your loop, add your tasks to a `List<Task>`, then afterwards call `Task.WhenAll`  on that list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fire off all tasks to process asynchronously then you need to, as Kevin says, start & add them into a `List<Task<T>>` and then call `Task.WhenAll` on that collection.

```
List<Task<DataTable>> dataTableTasks = new List<Task<DataTable>>();
foreach (FileInfo flInfo in dir.GetFiles())
{
    String name = flInfo.Name;
    Console.WriteLine("{0, -30:g} ", name);
    Task<DataTable> mergeTable = processFile(name);
    dataTableTasks.Add(mergeTable);
}

await Task.WhenAll(dataTableTasks);

foreach(Task<DataTable> dataTableTask in dataTableTasks)
{
    table.Merge(await dataTableTask);
}
```